# How do i create a VSCode task that calls a docker image, while at the same time being set to run whenever file changes occur on .md files?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, pandoc

I am currently creating a docker image to set up a pandoc environment that allows writing beautiful PDF's from markdown. I have made a template repository for writing these PDF's from VSCode (see https://github.com/niem94/template.pandoc-markdown), and for this, I want to create a task that is set to auto-run the docker image to compile the pdf whenever I make changes to the markdown files.

Does anyone have experience creating VSCode tasks that watch for file changes or run a docker image?

Comment: you've seen https://github.com/pandoc/dockerfiles  ?

Comment: Yeah, i use it in my own docker image, as i need to extend it to for my usecase. My problem is creating the VSCode task :-)